# create a table from total values fron all tables in athena

Tags: sql, database, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

table 1:

| name | rollno | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mark | 01 | 25 |
| ram | 02 | 30 |
| june | 03 | 45 |

table 2:

| emp.id | emp.name | emp.sal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | raj | 20000 |
| 02 | ram | 25000 |
| 03 | pie | 30000 |

table 3:

| pro.id | pro.name | pro.price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | dove | 40 |
| 02 | colgate | 60 |
| 03 | lays | 50 |

how do i query this in athena..?

my athena query:

```
>   create view table4
>     as
>     select sum(marks) as sumvalues 
>     from table1
>     union
>     select sum(emp.sal) as sumvalues 
>     from table 2
>     union
>     select sum(pro.price) as sumvalues
>     from table 3;
```

im getting output:

- id | sumvalues
- 01 |100
- 02 |75000
- 03 |150

i need table name or any field name in place of id like

table 4:

| name | sumvalues |
| --- | --- |
| marks | 100 |
| emp.sal | 75000 |
| pro.price | 150 |

Comment: Please tell us what Athena documentation pages on aggregation that you've looked at so far...

Comment: document -1 : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/considerations-ctas.html

Comment: document 2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html

Comment: So, what's your question then? What part of the documentation are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: i need to create table 4 from table 1 table 2 table 3.

Comment: i need totals of columns of all tables and display them in a different table

Comment: You haven't actually read the documentation, have you? Your comment-replies are just repeating your initial question without making any reference to the documentation.